# "Unresolved reference 'places'"

Tags: python, google-api, python-telegram-bot

I have 2 modules in my project. So its main and another. I'm trying to give value from second to main, but Ill take: "Unresolved reference 'places'"

```
#it's in main:


def location(update, context):

    message = update.message

    current_position = (message.location.latitude, message.location.longitude)

    current_position = geocoder(current_position)

    update.message.reply_text(places)# <-- this is it


#this is the second:
def geocoder(current_position):


    google_places = GooglePlaces(GL_TOKEN)
    query_result = google_places.nearby_search(language='ru',
                                               lat_lng={'lat': current_position[0], 'lng': current_position[1]},
                                               radius=5000,
                                               types=[types.TYPE_CAR_WASH])


    for place in query_result.places:

        place.get_details()
        places = (place.name, place.rating, place.local_phone_number, place.formatted_address)
        print(places) # <-- just looking for an answer in console


    return places
```

Comment: Welcome to stack you may want to review [Editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and read [ask]

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to import the second module in your main file

```
from second import geocoder
```

secondly, you called the second module function in current_position so the return value is stored in current_position

```
current_position = geocoder(current_position)
update.message.reply_text(current_position)
```

Comment: your welcome, kindly mark the answer as accepted